# How to fix my String Translation error in my selection list value?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am using the [String Translation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1279668) module (part of [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n)) and I have added new string in Italian language.

Example:
Data d'inizio

Output:

[image]

So instead of translated text Data d'inizio its shows me the drop-down text.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: This is a known bug in Drupal.  It has an RTBC patch, but it hasn't been committed yet.  I need to dig to find the issue link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed via a `hook_form_alter`, in which you loop through all select list options and run the option text through `decode_entities()`.

Refer to [HTML Encoding in Drupal Entity References](http://cscrunch.com/blog/corey-pennycuff/html-encoding-drupal-entity-references) for more details, which also includes this code sample:

```
function misc_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 $to_fix = array('field_reference');
 foreach($to_fix as $fix) {
   if (isset($form[$fix]) && isset($form[$fix][$form[$fix]['#language']]['#options'])) {
     foreach($form[$fix][$form[$fix]['#language']]['#options'] as &$text) {
       $text = decode_entities($text);
     }
   }
 }
```

}