# How to solve the apostrophe problem in node title? (&#039; -> ')

Tags: 7, theming

Node title includes **'** (apostrophe) and it appears normal while viewing the node. But in page source it appears as `&#039;`.

And for the same reason when I want to share this node on Twitter with some custom code put into node.tpl.php (`<?php print urlencode($title) ?>`) it also shows the ' as `&#039;`.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you want to say "appears" (or "is shown as") instead of "seems", no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue seems similar to what's written in issues such as [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1526142) or [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/691512).

The solution appears to be to use `decode_entities`, e.g. something like this:

```
$node->title = decode_entities($node->title);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm printing the titles with `<?php print $title; ?>` on node.tpl.php. I tried `print decode_entities($title);` but this didn't work. Where should I use this?

Comment: Bizarre (strange)! I thought your issue looked similar to what I wrote in [this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/178717/how-to-fix-my-string-translation-error-in-my-selection-list-value/178722#178722). So give me some more time to further think about this. While waiting, a (maybe silly) extra thought: could it be a cache issue why it didn't work "yet"?

Comment: Immm, sorry it works now :) I misused the code. Thanks.

Comment: Aha, so I was right about my "bizarre" (strange) ALSO ... thank you for confirming ... and the "accept" of course! Next question?!?!?!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was using a Token to capture my field and send it to Twitter. I solved it by changing which Token format I was using.

For example:

*Use*

`[node:field-twitter-message]`

*Instead of*

`[node:field_twitter_message]`